# Word length manipulation in data frame

Tags: r

I'm printing a data frame that should list word, length, and frequency in any simple text document. I have everything set but 1) length isn't counting the number of characters , I'm not sure what it's actually counting; and 2) I need to reorganize the word list from longest word to shortest for a final print of the list.

```
file <- c(scan("a.txt",character()))
file <- as.data.frame(table(file))

Freq <- file$Freq
Word <- file$file
Len <- sapply(c(Word),nchar)
```

A plane `a.txt` file with the following:

`the the the bus ran over two two people and when`

prints

```
Word Len Freq
1    and   1    1
2    bus   1    1
3   over   1    1
4 people   1    1
5    ran   1    1
6    the   1    3
7    two   1    2
8   when   1    1
```

Len should be the length of letters but here it always counts 1 - in longer tests it sometimes says 2 so I'm not sure what it counts. After this, it prints:

```
[1] and    bus    over   people ran    the    two    when  
Levels: and bus over people ran the two when
```

I'm trying to get the full word print to be in order from longest to shortest. I should be able to use `Len` to sort the words but I can't seem to get `sapply` to work right.

Comment: could you provide `dput(head(file))` in the question, just top few couple of rows and expected answer.

Comment: Is word a vector? If so you should be able to just use nchar directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to convert `file$file` (which is a factor here) to a string using `as.character()` and count its characters with simple [`nchar()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/nchar.html) without `sapply()` as R is vectorized.

```
file <- c(scan("a.txt",character()))
file <- as.data.frame(table(file))

Freq <- file$Freq
Word <- as.character(file$file)

Len <- nchar(Word)

x <- data.frame(Word, Len, Freq)
print(x)
print(Word[order(Len, decreasing = T)])
```

Ordering is done with [`order()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html).

Results:

```
print(x)
#     Word Len Freq
# 1    and   3    1
# 2    bus   3    1
# 3   over   4    1
# 4 people   6    1
# 5    ran   3    1
# 6    the   3    3
# 7    two   3    2
# 8   when   4    1

print(Word[order(Len, decreasing = T)])
# [1] "people" "over"   "when"   "and"    "bus"    "ran"    "the"    "two"
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the data frame also sort it by Len?

Comment: @user12027316 Yes, try `x[order(Len, decreasing = T), ]`

Answer (score 1):

With text produced by [Lorem Ipsum](https://www.lipsum.com/), this sequence of instructions does what the question asks for.

```
Word <- scan(file = 'a.txt', what = character())

Word <- gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', Word)    # remove punctuation characters
Word <- tolower(Word)                    # all characters lower case
tbl <- table(Word)                       # now get their frequencies
Len <- nchar(names(tbl))                 # the words are the table's names
x <- as.data.frame(tbl)                  # to data.frame
x$Len <- Len                             # assign the lengths column
```

The data is now in lexicographic order. If the class of `x$Word` is `"factor"`, use argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the call to `as.data.frame`.

Finally, order by `Len` and assign new row numbers.

```
x <- x[order(x$Len, decreasing = TRUE), ]
row.names(x) <- NULL
head(x)
#          Word Freq Len
#1 sollicitudin    3  12
#2 pellentesque    4  12
#3  ullamcorper    5  11
#4  suspendisse    1  11
#5  scelerisque    2  11
#6  consectetur    2  11
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data, but you could probably do something like this. The `$` operates to extract data by name, so `file$Freq` is getting the column `Freq` from the data.frame `file`.

```
file$Len <- nchar(file$file)

x <- file[,c('file', 'Len', 'Freq')]
names(x) <- c('Word', 'Len', 'Freq')
```

Answer (score 0):

length() is calculating vector length. For example:

```
x <- c("apple", "pie", "math", "this is sentance")
x
[1] "apple"            "pie"              "math"             "this is sentance"
length(x)
[1] 4
```

x is character vector of length 4 (it has 4 elements). If you want to calculate number of characters for each element in character vector use nchar():

```
nchar(x)
[1]  5  3  4 16
```

as you can see nchar() is vectorized - it calculates number of characters (not only letters) for each element in character vector.